# Import many .txt files, combine them into one data frame along with file names

Tags: r, import, dataframe

I have many `.txt` files. You can download [2 of them from here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1m5sz17xofelwah/AAAFUfGZh1Pg7hfR8mKjOva3a?dl=0). 
I imported them into RStudio and combined them into one `data.frame` using the code below

```
setwd("C:/Users/aelwan/Dropbox/import_txt")
data<-do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = ".txt"), 
                            read.table, 
                            header=T))
    head(data, 12)
     observed    simulated
1         2         4
2         5         5
3         5         2
4         2         5
5         5         2
6         2        12
7         1        56
8         2        75
9         3        78
10        6        75
11        7        65
12        7        53
```

I'd like to add the file name as well to the `data.frame`to be like below

```
     observed    simulated    ID
1         2         4         simu1           
2         5         5         simu1
3         5         2         simu1
4         2         5         simu1
5         5         2         simu1
6         2        12         simu1
7         1        56         simu2
8         2        75         simu2
9         3        78         simu2
10        6        75         simu2
11        7        65         simu2
12        7        53         simu2
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `for` loop then you can add the numerical label column you want:

```
files.list <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
df <- data.frame(observed=integer(),
                 simulated=integer(),
                 ID=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1: length(files.list)) {
    df.next <- read.table(files.list[[i]], header=TRUE)
    df.next$ID <- paste0('simu', i)
    df <- rbind(df, df.next)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your time and help. It is not simu1 only. There is simu2 as well. In addition, actual number of files are from simu1 to simu70 (total of 70 text files representing 70 simulations.

Comment: I could have created the 3rd column ID myself if all the .txt files have the exact number of rows. However, they have different number of rows. I thought there could be a way to import the file name (without .txt) and add it to the ID column.

Comment: Many thanks Tim. I really appreciate your time and help. It works perfectly
:)