# Read and save the results from multiple file into the same dataframe

Tags: r

I have many different files in the same directory.

I use this this to take all files.

```
 setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/mydata")
 temp = list.files(pattern="myfile_.+\\.csv")
 myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

All files have the same name columns.

I would like to create a df which will contain the data of all files as it is like using read.csv() for a unique file.

I tried this:

```
df <- read.csv(file=myfiles, header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

but the error is this:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

How can I fix it?

The following line from here read the files and create different dataframe for every file.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="badges_.+\\.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Is it possible to use it but into one df?

Comment: Take a look at answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132265/r-importing-many-files-at-the-same-time-and-adding-id-indicator

Comment: @CPak thank you it is a little cofused for me because I don't have so many problems.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `dplyr::bind_rows()` function to combine your `myfiles` into one data.frame. You can save this afterwards like a normal data frame.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/mydata")
temp = list.files(pattern="myfile_.+\\.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)
big_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(myfiles)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But in the result I have one column in which the values are comma separated